# html and css coding not connecting

Tags: css

I just indexed my website on Google. However, somehow my html and css are not connected correctly as the website is completely broken.

I have included a pic of my index coding as well as a link to my website. Also include is a pic of how my root folder is organized.

It seems that I can't post screenshots as I don't have a 10 reputation, so I'll try to do a cut and paste of the coding and hope that is sufficient.

Also, all of my folders are contained within my root-folder which is labeled as Comics Website with sub-folders contained within the root-folder and labeled as html, css, images, and content with some sub-folders contained within the folders as described.
Any aid would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>ICUWebcomics</title>
        <link href="CSS/drop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link href="CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script src="/Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

<body>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://icuwebcomics.comeze.com/) your website? The links to CSS/drop.css, CSS/styles.css and /Scripts/swfobject_modified.js are all returning with `404 Not Found` errors. You probably uploaded your files to the wrong place.

Comment: open the filemanager and then upload all files in  public_html/

Comment: Actually, after much experimentation with uploading the site, I realized that  the problem was that I had connected sub-folders connected to the main root folder. In theory, this practice of organization works well in Dreamweaver, however, having sub-folders that contain separate files such as CSS in one sub-folder and HTML contained in a different sub-folder all within the same root-folder doesn't jive well when uploading the site in the public_html directory. to make this work, I had to dump everything into one folder within the root-folder. However, thanks for the response.